# There's any tricks to find the specific xpath

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to get some prices for google-sheets-importxml from different sites. 
Some were very easy, other i can't find the correct xpath.

There's any tricks? How do you find them?

Thanks a lot

Comment: rightclick and inspect element

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer, i know that but some times i can't get the correct value.

i use the following xpath to get the price with success:

```
 //div/div/span[@class='real price'] 

//div/div/div/div/span
```

Can i find the correct xpath in this code:

```
<span class="regular-price" id="product-price-11374"> 
<!--span class="price-label"></span--> 
<span class="price">1&nbsp;490,00&nbsp;€</span> 
</span>
```